# CSS or jQuery modification to prevent screen flicker

Tags: jquery, css, image, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I've got an image viewer/enlarger working with jQuery UI sortable.  When there are quite a few images, the window becomes scrollable in order to accomodate them.  When this is the case, the images are jerky when dragged from one place to another.  The scrollbar that appears will jump as well.

The original CSS I had worked in everything but IE.  I then generated some new CSS and it now works in all browsers, but I have to keep the area of the viewer relatively small, which is not ideal if there are lots of images (i.e. some are completely hidden and dragging becomes difficult).  It seems to only happen when the actual area of the viewer goes beyond the window boundary.  I am open to solutions through CSS or jQuery.  Tried CSS first b/c that's what I know better.  Thanks!

**First, here is the jQuery:**

```
    $(document).ready(function($){
var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var agentID = deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/);
if (agentID) {

    $("#gallery, #viewer").sortable({
        connectWith: ".images",
        items: "div",
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        forceHelperSize: true,
        receive: function (event, ui) {
            switch (ui.item.parent().attr("id")) {
                case "viewer":
                    ui.item.animate({ height: "250px", width: "250px" });
                    break;
                case "gallery":
                    ui.item.animate({ height: "96px", width: "96px" });
                    break;
            }
        }

    }).disableSelection();

}

else {
    $("#gallery, #viewer").sortable({
        connectWith: ".images",
        items: "div",
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        forceHelperSize: true,
        receive: function (event, ui) {
            switch (ui.item.parent().attr("id")) {
                case "viewer":
                    ui.item.css({ height: "525px", width: "auto" });
                    break;
                case "gallery":
                    ui.item.css({ height: "150px", width: "auto" });
                    break;
            }
        }

    }).disableSelection();
}
```

});

**The CSS that will not jump in everything but IE:**

```
        html, body {min-height:100%;}
    .hangingIndent{ padding-left:22px; text-indent:-22px;}
    #gallery {width: 95%; min-height: 100px; overflow:auto; *overflow:inherit; margin-bottom: 10px;}
    *html #gallery {height: 100px; }
    #gallery .image {float: left; width: auto; height: 150px; padding: 0; margin-right: 10px; text-align: center; background-color:#e2e2e2;}
    #gallery .image img { width: auto; height: 148px; border: solid 1px black; cursor: move; }
    #viewer {width: 95%; min-height: 250px; background-color:#A3A3A3; padding: 1%; overflow:auto; *overflow:inherit;}
    * html #viewer {height: 250px;}
    #viewer .image {float: left; height: 325px; width: auto; padding: 0; margin-right: 10px; text-align: center; background-color:#e2e2e2;}
    #viewer .image img {width: auto; height: 525px; border: solid 3px white; cursor: move; }
    #viewer h4 {line-height: 1em; margin: 0 0 0.4em; color:#000;}
```

**And the CSS that will work in all, but enlarged images are within the scrollable area:**

```
        html, body {min-height:100%;}
    .hangingIndent{ padding-left:22px; text-indent:-22px;}
    #gallery
    {
        width: 95%;
        min-height: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        overflow: auto;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #gallery {}
    #gallery .image {float: left; width: auto; height: 150px; padding: 0; margin-right: 10px; text-align: center; background-color:#e2e2e2;}
    #gallery .image img { width: auto; height: 148px; border: solid 1px black; cursor: move; }
    #viewer
    {
        width: 95%;
        height: 250px;
        min-height: 250px;
        background-color: #A3A3A3;
        padding: 1%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
        #viewer .image
        {
            float: left;
            height: 325px;
            width: auto;
            padding: 0;
            margin-right: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #e2e2e2;
                border:none;
        }
            #viewer .image img
            {
                width: auto;
                height: 525px;
                border: solid 3px white;
                cursor: move;
            }
    #viewer h4 {line-height: 1em; margin: 0 0 0.4em; color:#000;}
```

**And the HTML:**

```
    <div id="gallery" class="images">
<div class="ui-corner-tr image"><img src="../../../../../images/Fig267b.jpg" alt="" title="" /></div>
<div class="ui-corner-tr image"><img src="../../../../../images/Question_9a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></div>
<div class="ui-corner-tr image"><img src="../../../../../images/Question_9b.jpg" alt="" title="" /></div>
<div class="ui-corner-tr image"><img src="../../../../../images/Question_9c.jpg" alt="" title="" /></div>
<div class="ui-corner-tr image"><img src="../../../../../images/xray1.JPG" alt="" title="" /></div>
<div class="ui-corner-tr image"><img src="../../../../../images/xray2.JPG" alt="" title="" /></div>
</div>
<div id="viewer" class="images">
<h4>Drag the images to the area above to remove them from the viewing tool.</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding overflow: hidden; to the parent element. I'm not sure if this will work in this case, but it often gets rid of 'flickering' effect.